# Why aren't these two string equals?

Tags: java, udp

I am sending a packet through UDP and for some reason I can't compare the string I extract from the packet and the string I create even though the values are the same when I print them (no trailing white spaces).

```
byte[] incoming = new byte[1000];
DatagramPacket request = new DatagramPacket(incoming, incoming.length);
serverSocket.receive(request);
String str = new String(request.getData());
String str2 = new String("message received");

if(str.equals(str2))
{
   System.out.println("equal");
}
```

Is there any reason for this?

Comment: Check length of the strings. There must be error in your transmission.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This occurs because `new String(request.getData())` does *not* return `"message received"`.

The problem is [likely] due to the fact that `new String(byte[])` attempts to use *all* (1000 of) the bytes supplied, in the default encoding, which ends with a bunch of NUL ('\0') characters that append to the actual string content making it *not equal* with the literal. Such can be easily seen a debugger, although such NUL characters are often "lost" when displaying as normal text as with `println`.

Trivially: `"hello".equals("hello\0")` is false.

Several solutions include:

1. *Frame* the string, such as prefixing the sent data with the number of bytes that make up the string, and then using [a String constructor that takes a limit/length](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String-byte:A-int-int-java.lang.String-) or;
2. *Prevent* any trailing 0 from being processed, again by specifiying the limit to decode or;
3. *Remove* any NUL characters after decoding the data.

Since option #3 is easy<sup>1</sup> (until it can be fixed to use #1/#2), consider:

```
String str = new String(request.getData(), "UTF-8"); // Specify an encoding!
int nul = str.indexOf('\0');
if (nul > -1) {
   str = str.substring(0, nul);
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup> While trimming is the easiest, it is *not* generally appropriate. The biggest problem with #3 over #2 is it first decodes *all* the bytes and *then* filters the characters. Under different encodings (although ASCII and UTF-8 should be "safe"), this may result in non-NUL garbage after the actual string content depending upon what exists in the buffer.

Also, specify an encoding manually to `new String(byte[] ..)` or `String.getBytes(..)`. Otherwise the "default encoding" will be used, which can cause problems if the different systems are using a different default.